# Behaviour of lastAccessTime BasicFileAttributes..

Tags: java, nio, file-attributes

I would like to know what I should do in order to change the return value of lastAccessTime

```
System.out.println("Last Access time is:"+basicAttributes.lastAccessTime());
System.out.println("Last Modified time:"+basicAttributes.lastModifiedTime());
```

Even though I access the file I called the readAttributes on.. the lastAccessTime() methods does not update the value with the time I last accessed the file.. I am using ubuntu and that attribute should be supported..
What's wrong with that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operating system isn't obliged to update the directory every time you access the file. Mostly they do it when you close the file.