# Why is LastAccessTime not changing when a file is accessed?

Tags: powershell

Why is `LastAccessTime` not changing when the file is accessed? What does `LastAccessTime` really mean?

```
PS C:\src\t> Get-Date

Monday, March 22, 2021 09:18:19


PS C:\src\t> Get-Content .\t.txt
adsf
asdfa asdf asdf asd f
a
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
safd
asdf;lkj a;kja;k
PS C:\src\t> (Get-ChildItem .\t.txt).LastAccessTime

Wednesday, December 4, 2019 17:30:23
```

Is this considered a bug? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18114053/447901

Comment: Perhaps it's simply [disabled](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/139015-enable-disable-ntfs-last-access-time-stamp-updates-windows-10-a.html)  on your system. It is on mine. What does `fsutil behavior query disablelastaccess` returns?

Comment: Are you giving it time to update and refreshing the file system? Could be that it only updates at certain times like ADs "LastLogonTimeStamp"

Comment: Similar question from SU: https://superuser.com/a/251265/1077440

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, my HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate value is 3. The `fsutil` command returns `DisableLastAccess = 3  (System Managed, Enabled)`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, it has been 1.5 hours. Should it have updated by now?

Comment: The volume is > 128 GiB. This appears to explain the situation. https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/139015-enable-disable-ntfs-last-access-time-stamp-updates-windows-10-a.html#:~:text=Enable%20or%20Disable%20NTFS%20Last%20Access%20Time%20Stamp,System%20Managed%2C%20Last%20Access%20Time%20Updates%20...%20

Comment: Some very clever person at Microsoft decided that `DisableLastAccess` should be called `Enabled` if last access timestamps are disabled (and the same for all the other `Disable*` features, rather than using something like `true` or `false`. It's not the case that I don't find this pointlessly confusing.